# get the data from an api with json and php

Tags: php, json

I have data in this format from an API:

```
 {
 "key1": 2300,
 "key2": 152,
  "key3": 5,
  "key4": 18,
  "key5": "value",
  "players": [
    {
      "avatar": {
        "name": "name",
        "id": 73019554141,
        "key": 34361224375
      }]
     "players": [
    {
      "avatar": {
        "name": "name",
        "id": 73019554141,
        "key": 34361224375
      }]
      }
```

I'm using `$jsondata = file_get_contents($url); //get the content from the url` and `$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);` to retrieve the data. I can access the data using:

```
      $key1= $data['key1'];
      $key2= $data['key2'];
```

How do I get the player values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid.  Assuming the below JSON, it would be as follows:

```
$jsondata='{
    "key1": 2300,
    "key2": 152,
    "key3": 5,
    "key4": 18,
    "key5": "value",
    "players": [
        {
            "avatar": {
                "name": "name",
                "id": 73019554141,
                "key": 34361224375
            }
        }
    ]
}';

$data=json_decode($jsondata);

echo($data->players[0]->avatar->name.' '.$data->players[0]->avatar->id.' '.$data->players[0]->avatar->key);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f9d8227def5042d2c7280816c39fc9edc514263